# is it possible to block a specific cookie from being setup using javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, blocking

I am working on a Wordpress website to make it GDPR cookie law compliance. So I am wondering if it is possible to block a specific cookie from being setup using javascript?

Let's say I have a cookie named as "_example". I need to block this from being set up. How can I do this?

Comment: Please check this [GDPR solution](https://www.cookieyes.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/709281/how-to-block-a-specific-cookie-from-a-specific-site

By default, browsers don't allow such a fine-grained control over cookies: usually you can either block all third-party cookies or block all cookies for a given domain.